# Receive @@IDENTITY from MSSQL on Oracle side

Tags: sql-server, oracle, plsql

Can I receive @@IDENTITY from MSSQL on Oracle side?

I insert into operation_tab operation values. Table has operation_tab has also column seq_id that is autoincrement on MSSQL site

```
DECLARE
  stmt_        VARCHAR2(32000);
  operation_   VARCHAR2(100);
  seq_id_      NUMBER;
BEGIN   
   stmt_ := 'INSERT INTO operation_tab@mydblink ( ' ||
                        'OPERATION    ) ' ||   
                 ' VALUES (:1)'||
                 ' RETURNING seq_id INTO :2';                                  
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt_ USING IN operation_, OUT seq_id_;
END;
```

Below code does not work because MSSQL does not know returning keywords.
How can I receive seq_id? Searching the internet, I found that I can use

```
SELECT @@IDENTITY
```

But how I can do it from the Oracle side?

Comment: *"But how i can do it from oracle site?"* You can't. `@@IDENTITY` is a SQL Server system function; you can't use it from a different RDBMS, or even a separate connection. you need to use it in the batch that performs the `INSERT`.

Comment: You cannot run Oracle SQL syntax on SQL Server database. Likewise you cannot run MSSQL on an Oracle database  You need to figure out what code you actually need to run and where you need to run it. For instance, does your MSSQL database really need to know the ID of a new record in Oracle? What's it going to do with it? Maybe you need to re-think your approach?

Comment: @APC I create record in operation_tab  and then in operation_line_tab i have to use id from operation_tab  to create new record. What i did now is i get max(id) from operation_tab after the insert. I do not like this solution i ahve did now. Meaby beter way will be resigon to autoincrement on MSSQL site (but this is othere comapny system) or create function on MSSQL site that will return value of @@IDENTITY

Comment: I think you may have suggested the best solution yourself. Create a function in the MSSQL database to perform the INSERT and then return the value you need.

Comment: You may want to edit your question and change "MSSQL" to "SQL Server" as that is the correct name.